# "They reported being told to..." Trying to explain

Tags: verbs, complements

I have never really thought about this one before, but out of curiosity, is it grammatical to have "being" after the verb "report"? Here is an example:
"They reported being told to stay behind the yellow line."
What role does "being" play?

Comment: Yes, it's grammatical, and so is _They reported having been told to.._. The role of _being_ (and of _been_ in the one above) is to be the auxiliary verb for the Passive construction, which consists of some form of the auxiliary verb _be_ followed immediately by the past participle of some transitive verb (here it's _told_, the past participle of _tell_). The reason why -_ing_ forms are OK after _report_ is because _report_ allows a gerund complement. Every verb has its own rules about stuff like that.

Comment: @JohnLawler A gerund that is a complement, or a complement of a gerund?

Comment: A gerund that is a complement. There are four major types of complement clause, two finite and two non-finite. The non-finite ones are the gerund and the infinitive complement types.

Comment: @JohnLawler ...and that-clause and embedded question, right? I figured it was acting like a gerund. Sometimes I tend to overthink these things. This all stemmed from a question that a coworker asked me. Also, is there a way to promote your comment to an answer?

Comment: –ing form can be object/complement/subject or noun-substitutes. So GERUND that is a complement

Comment: If you get over the yellow line you will *be told* where to go.

Answer (score 1):

In comments, John Lawler wrote:

> Yes, it's grammatical, and so is *They reported having been told to..*. The role of *being* (and of *been* in the one above) is to be the auxiliary verb for the Passive construction, which consists of some form of the auxiliary verb *be* followed immediately by the past participle of some transitive verb (here it's *told*, the past participle of *tell*). The reason why -*ing* forms are OK after *report* is because *report* allows a gerund complement. Every verb has its own rules about stuff like that.
>
> There are four major types of complement clause, two finite and two non-finite. The non-finite ones are the gerund and the infinitive complement types.

Answer (score 0):

As found from @JohnLawler's [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/490605/they-reported-being-told-to-trying-to-explain#comment1183839_490605), the sentence is indeed grammatical. "Being" is a gerund that complements the verb "reported". It is also known as an auxiliary word that links to "told", a past participle.